# How do you go faster in minecraft(Without useing the potion of swiftness)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, a friend showed me a thing where you go super fast in Minecraft and I totally forgot it. So, I was wondering if any of you knew what it was.

Comment: Your tag doesnt make much sense, ftl is a game, and your question is a little too vague to try and answer. You might want to add more details about the thing your friend showed you.

Comment: There are many, many ways you can go faster. You will need to narrow down your question before we can provide you with an answer.

Comment: I think I have a video sitting on my channel [somewhere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXT7wnOLzWI) with almost exactly that title...

Comment: Ok so, my friend showed me something that included typing it the typing area and you include your Minecraft online name.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to go fast without commands then here is a helpful video:

**This part will only work in creative mode or with cheats enabled on LAN:**

If what you want is a command to give you speed then this command will make you go as fast as you want: Just type in the chat `/effect (name) minecraft:speed 10000 100` the first number is how long you wish the command to last, and the second is how fast you wish to go. To get rid of the speed type `/effect *player* clear` (or drink milk).

Comment: Yes! That was it and it worked!

Comment: Hitting the answered button is always appreciated (:

Answer (score 1):

By pressing forward twice, you'll sprint. But this can deplete your hunger and when it's at a certain point, you can't sprint. Sprinting and jumping at the same time increases the speed. Sprinting and jumping in a 2 block space area makes it even more faster. With ice added on the ground, you go even more faster! And with closed trapdoors, you run the fastest without a potion of swiftness. [I learned this all and tried it out and it worked.]